# Maintain Scroll Position of GridView through Screen Rotation

Tags: android, gridview, orientation

How can I maintain the scroll position of a GridView (it's filled with search results) throughout a screen reorientation?

I have the GridView inside a Fragment, and when I rotate the screen it jumps back up to the top of the list.

To make it even more tricky, in landscape mode my GridView has 3 columns.. in portrait mode it has 2 columns.

I can't seem to figure out how to keep the fragment's GridView scrolled to anywhere near where it should be when the screen orientation changes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try this:

Initially you have to get the current scrolling position of the GridView by calling:

```
int index = gridview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Then you have to save this value while orientation changes and when the GridView is created again you have to move your gridview to this index.

I suppose this could work:

```
gridview.smoothScrollToPosition(int index)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I saw that, but I need to support back to 2.1 and so I don't have access to smoothScrollToPosition(). I'm using setSelection(int position) instead. getFirstVisiblePosition() is exactly what I needed. Now I feel silly! Thank you!

Comment: In my app, smoothScrollToPosition does not work. But setSelection works fine.

Comment: This solution is not the best, consider lots of items, scroll will take long time. gridView.setSelection(index); solve the problem by putting directly the list to the right position.

Answer (score 24):

You can use the following method, it will work for all Android versions.

To save the current scrolling position:

```
int index = gridView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Then after orientation change, use the following code to set the gridView position to the saved index:

```
gridView.setSelection(index);
```

Comment: this worked!!!!    gridview.smoothScrollToPosition(int index)---> will not work when there is lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

Using of **getFirstVisiblePosition()** is good, but I've found a nice solution, just to save a state of view.

```
//state of view (includes scroll position) as a Parceble
Parcelable mobileGalleryState = gridView.onSaveInstanceState();

//just restore previous state including all changes are made before
gridView.onRestoreInstanceState(mobileGalleryState);
```

By the way, you can use it for ListView also.

Comment: Great answer. I like it more, because the real scroll position is maintained. When just selecting an item the position is slightly (about 100px) different in my case.